# Elasticsearch: new type or new index?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am doing a test, gathering tweets from the Twitter API, and index some of the information in Elasticsearch.

As we all know, Elasticsearch doesn't handle well *array of objects*. And I need those for some analysis. Examples of arrays of objects from a tweet could be:

- List of urls contained in the text, with information about domain, or other things
- List of mentions contained in the text, with information about the user (like join date, user_id)
- Tokens and semantyc analysis from the text.

Kibana doesn't handle well, as well, array of objects and it makes a nightmare to visualize these objects. So I was thinking to *flat* those objects in a new index or a new type of the same index, putting in some information abbout the origin `tweet`.

What is better? a new index? a new type? and why? 
how can I make a visualization on Kibana that takes in consideratio the id from another type/index? which is better?

Comment: Check if nested types (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) can help.

Comment: Kibana doesn't support nested types. Here is a good write-up on the removal of types and other options in Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html. You can also nest the property names under a single type, like what we did in Kibana: https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-6-removal-of-mapping-types

Answer (score 0):

Mapping types are deprecated in elasticsearch 6.x and will be removed in 7.x. So I guess a new index is the way to go.